# Возможно ли сохранить коллайдер в меш?

Tags: unity3d, mesh

Компонент **MeshCollider** при включенном параметре **Convex** создает "упрощенный" (по сравнению с моделью) коллайдер (*на рисунке слева*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли сохранить этот коллайдер как меш? Или как можно получить информацию о вершинах такого коллайдера?

Пробовал создавать и сохранять меш, копируя информацию о вершинах из **sharedMesh.vertices**, но новый меш получался точной копией оригинала (*как на рисунке справа*).

**UPD**

Решение получено. И результат соответствует ожиданию. Черный цвет - получившийся меш, зеленые линии - коллайдер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут уже надо лезть в исходники, велика вероятность, что эта меш генерится в рантайме == ее никак не достать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница между обычным и convex мешем с точки зрения реализации заключается только в алгоритме. Convex меш использует алгоритм, который делает меш выпуклой формы без дыр. Достать этот меш колаидра из Unity, скорее всего, не получится нормальными методами. Однако, можно заметить, что сам редактор Unity генерирует и тот и другой меш достаточно быстро - значит можно самому применить алгоритм для создания такого меша.

Тут можно посмотреть в сторону существующих решений, например [MIConvexHull](https://designengrlab.github.io/MIConvexHull/). Это библиотека для .NET 4.5, которая, судя по примерам работает достаточно быстро даже для использования в рантайме. Несмотря на то, что сама библиотека никак не связана с Unity, есть [пруф на официальном форуме](https://answers.unity.com/questions/983425/creating-a-convex-mesh-not-collider.html), где ребятам удалось завести эту библиотеку в Unity без особых усилий.

В качестве примера скорости работы, можно привести такую модель и сгенерированный меш:
[image: Модель] [image: полученный меш]

Скорость обработки:

> 26332 vertices: Convex hull in 0.003s. Triangulation in 0.761s.

Есть вероятность, что созданный таким образом меш не будет 100% идентичен Unity Convex Collider, но судя по примеру, результат достаточно близкий к тому, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно! Меш получается практически идентичный виду коллайдера (результат разместил внизу вопроса).

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский как по скорости работы? реально ли использовать в рантайме?

Comment: 3700 verts -> в 67 verts вместе с сохранением на HDD - 0,508 сек. 48500 verts -> в 2270 verts - 0,762 сек.

Comment: хороший результат. Можно и в рантайме вполне пробовать к применению